# Should my generic template use T or T&&?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am working in a file that has a given function with many overloads, like so:

```
inline X f(ScriptWrappable* impl, Y y, Z z) { ... }
inline X f(Node* impl, Y y, Z z) { ... }
inline X f(RawPtr<T> impl, Y y, Z z) { ... }
inline X f(const RefPtr<T>& impl, Y y, Z z) { ... }
inline X f(ScriptWrappable* impl, Y y, Z z) { ... }
inline X f(const String& impl, Y y, Z z) { ... }
inline X f(int64_t impl, Y y, Z z) { ... }
template<typename T, size_t capacity> inline X f(const Vector<T, capacity>& impl, Y y, Z z) { ... }
```

I am trying to add a new overload that only requires one parameter, like so:

```
template<typename T> inline X f(T impl, W w) {
  return f(impl, w->getY(), w->getZ());
}
```

I am using templates so that all of the above variations automatically work with my new two-parameter version.

However, during code review I was asked, "Is `T&&` better for avoiding copy?". That is, should I instead do

```
template<typename T> inline X f(T&& impl, W w) {
  return f(impl, w->getY(), w->getZ());
}
```

I don't really know the answer to this question. I thought I understood universal references, but I am not familiar with when they are a good idea or not. What would be the consequences in my situation of choosing one over the other?

If I had to guess, I'd say that since the original types that T can stand in for are all simple to copy (primitives, references, or pointers) T&& will not give much benefit. But I'm still curious if e.g. any types could be passed to the T&& version that could not be passed to the T version, or vice versa.

Comment: If the caller wants to move, he should only `std::move` the argument. By using `T&&` you're **forcing** him to do it. By using only `T` you're giving him a choice.

Comment: this is not true when using templates in deduced context

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: const reference seems enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should write your function like this:

```
template<typename T> inline X f(T&& impl, W w) {
  return f(std::forward<T>(impl), w->getY(), w->getZ());
}
```

This is called perfect forwarding. The type of `impl` will be exactly the same as if you had called `f` directly. It will *not* necessarily be an r-value reference.

Comment: Thank you! It does sound like perfect forwarding matches my intent better. I'm still hoping to understand what would happen differently if I'd chosen the other alternatives, but searching for "perfect forwarding" gives me pages like http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/ which seem to help.

Comment: Have a look at Richard Hodges' answer.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt, Unless f is meant to take ownership of impl, Why not use const T&.

Comment: @JohanLundberg `T&&` is more general. For example if `T = int` and there is an overload `f(int, Y, Z)`, that overload will be picked. If there only is an overload for `f(const int &, Y, Z)` then that will be picked. This moves the choice of whether to use pass-by-value or pass-by-const-ref to the implementation of the (non-template) `f`, where it belongs.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt, "This moves the choice of ...  to ... f, where it belongs". Clear point, and I agree.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a little complex because it requires some understanding of the compiler's rules regarding templates.

In the following declaration:

```
template<class T> void func(T&& t);
```

T is evaluated in *deduced context* and as a result will be treated by the compiler *either* as an r-value reference or a l-value reference, whichever is appropriate. Coupled with the use of `std::forward` (note: in this case *not* `std::move`) this results in perfect forwarding and is optimally efficient.

However, this is not being evaluated in deduced context:

```
template<class T>
struct X {
  void foo(T&& t);
};
```

In this case, foo is in fact demanding an r-value reference.

Neither is this deduced context:

```
template<class T>
void foo(std::vector<T>&& v);
```

In these two cases, you should use `std::move`.

Comment: It isn't the evaluation of `T` in a deduced context that makes it either an r-value or l-value reference.  `typedef int& T; typedef T&& X;` has no deduced context, yet `X` is of type `int&`.  Replace with `typedef int T;` and `X` becomes of type `int&&`.  There is no magic involving deduction involved in making `T&&` either an rvalue or lvalue reference; that is reference collapse rules.  The deduction rules do result in `T` in `T&&` being deduced in certain ways to allow said rules to generate either an l or r value reference, but that is a real difference.

Comment: Forgive me if I have the wording wrong. What is the correct form of words?

Comment: Those who can, post.  Those who cannot, critique other's posts.  :)    The choice of words required to talk about template type deduction from function arguments and forwarding references is *hard*.